# How to handle Many to Many records, when using Rails as REST API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my app, you can sign up as Company, and a company can add services that the company provides for users. These services is pickable from a list, in the companies preferences.

So i have a Many to Many relationship between the two of them.

```
class Company < User
  has_and_belongs_to_many :services
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :services
end

class Service < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :companies
  default_scope order('name ASC')
end
```

Now my problem is that don't what Rails expects from in the put request, this is what i currently for for my companies controller.

```
  def update
    company = Company.find(params[:id])
    if company == current_user && company.update_attributes(company_params)
      respond_with company
    else
      render json: {errors: company.errors}
    end
  end

  private

  def company_params
    params.require(:company).permit(:name, :email, :phone, services_attributes: [:service_id])
  end
```

So i am trying to send the id's of the selected services the company made, and the request payload looks something like this.

```
{"company": {
  "name":"Elvar's biks",
  "email":"fsfsdfsdf@sdf.com",
  "service_attributes": [{"id":"3"},{"id":"6"}]}}
```

But this yields

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound at /api/companies/2
================================================

> Couldn't find Service with ID=3 for Company with ID=2
```

How should i approach this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I turns out i did't need the accepts_nested_attributes_for method, neither should i have used services_attributes: [:service_id], for working with Many to Many.

Instead rails expects

```
service_ids: []
```

Notice [], this tells Rails to expect a array.

Updating with,

```
company.update_attributes(company_params)
```

now correctly adds the relation records in companies_services tables.

The final company params

```
params.require(:company).permit(:name, :email, :phone, service_ids: [])
```